# Hooking up domain name

Tags: iis, web-server, hosting, vps

I have just registered a domain name (www.belfastmasters.co.uk) and want to hook it up to an IIS web server that I have set up on a Virtual Private Server.  I am getting into the relms of the unknown a bit, I have set this kind of thing up before but this time I am using a different DNS provider and I think I need to set up an A-Record.

I have done this and pointed it to the correct IP, set up the IIS settings to look for the domain name and point to the right website but still I get nothing.

Could anyone clarify what the steps are to get this to work and where I may be going wrong please?

Answer (score 1):

Your domain is not being served properly.

```
red-dragon# dig www.belfastmasters.co.uk

; <<>> DiG 9.5.0-P2 <<>> www.belfastmasters.co.uk
;; global options:  printcmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 59085
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.belfastmasters.co.uk.      IN      A

;; Query time: 60 msec
;; SERVER: 10.42.255.254#53(10.42.255.254)
;; WHEN: Wed Dec  2 13:54:20 2009
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 42

red-dragon# dig belfastmasters.co.uk soa

; <<>> DiG 9.5.0-P2 <<>> belfastmasters.co.uk soa
;; global options:  printcmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 46502
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;belfastmasters.co.uk.          IN      SOA

;; Query time: 114 msec
;; SERVER: 10.42.255.254#53(10.42.255.254)
;; WHEN: Wed Dec  2 13:55:10 2009
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 38
```

**Once it is...**
You need to set up an A record pointing to your VPS IP address.